# How to pass model (Asp.net MVC) as a datasource for jQuery DataTables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a controller method like this:

```
public ActionResult GetInterviews(DTParameterModel dtParamModel)

{ ....some code, mapping.......

IEnumerable<InterviewViewModel> lstvmInterviews = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Interview>, IEnumerable<InterviewViewModel>>(lstInterviews);

}
```

Normally, I would pass `lstvmInterviews` (list of my ViewModel) as an IEnumerable to the view.

Now I am using DataTable (1.10). I don't know how to pass this as a DataSource?

I am trying something like this, but its all messed up.

```
/* sort of RnD-ing here */

        var vmInterviews = from vmInterview in lstvmInterviews
                           select new[] { new { vmInterview.InterviewID, vmInterview.InterviewTitle,
                         vmInterview.InterviewDate } };


    //    return Json(new
    //    {
    //        sEcho = dtParamModel.Order,
    //        iTotalRecords = vmInterviews.Count(),
    //        iTotalDisplayRecords = 10,
    //        aaData = vmInterviews
    //    },
    //    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    //    //return View("Interviews", lstvmInterviews);
    //}
```

Can't seem to find the right example. How do you implement this?

The View:

```
<table id="dtInterviews" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>INTERVIEW ID</th>
        <th>INTERVIEW TITLE </th>
        <th>DATE OF INTERVIEW</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dtInterviews').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/GetInterviews",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "InterviewID" },
            { "data": "InterviewTitle" },
            { "data": "InterviewDate" },
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery only understand json arrays.  You should be able to serialize your vmInterviews object using a json serializer and return that.

Comment: Yes but this is specific to DataTables. I don't know what parameters to pass, and how to pass them.

Comment: See this article -> **https://www.echosteg.com/jquery-datatables-asp.net-mvc5-server-side** or this older generic script -> **https://datatables.net/development/server-side/asp_net** Dont know if it is any worth